# Sufficiently large integers can be partitioned into squares of distinct integers whose reciprocals sum to 1.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, oeis, egyptian-fractions

OEIS sequence [A297895](https://oeis.org/A297895) describes

> Numbers that can be partitioned into squares of distinct integers whose reciprocals sum to 1.

```
1, 49, 200, 338, 418, 445, 486, 489, 530, 569, 609, 610, 653, 770, 775, 804, 845, 855, 898, 899, 939, 978, 1005, 1019, 1049, 1065, 1085, 1090, 1134, 1194, 1207, 1213, 1214, 1254, 1281, 1308, 1356, 1374, 1379, 1382, 1415, 1434, 1442, 1457, 1458, 1459, 1475, 1499, 1502, 1522, 1543, 1566, 1570, 1582
```

For example, $$
  49 = 2^2 + 3^2 + 6^2 \text{ and } \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} = 1;\\
  200 = 2^2 + 4^2 + 6^2 + 12^2 \text{ and } \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12} = 1.
$$

---

The author claims that

> All integers $\geq 8543$ belong to this sequence.

What is a proof (or even a heuristic) that explains why this is the case?

Comment: I sent an email to the author (Max Alekseyev) and he said: "I have just submitted a paper proving exactly this. I'll post a preprint to arXiv some time this week. So stay tuned."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As promised, here is my preprint with a proof that all integers $\geq 8543$ belong to [A297895](https://oeis.org/A297895):

[On partitions into squares of distinct integers whose reciprocals sum to 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.05928)

Questions and comments are welcome.